# Explicit example of a Fourier transform of $f \in L^2(\mathbb R) \setminus L^1(\mathbb R)$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, education, harmonic-analysis

The Fourier transform shall be defined by

$$
    \hat f(\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-2\pi i \cdot \xi x} dx
$$

The Fourier transform is well-defined for $f \in L^1(\mathbb R)$, that is, $f$ absolutely integrable, as can easily be checked.

However, we also know that the Fourier transform is well-defined for $f \in L^2(\mathbb R)$. In textbooks, this is usually shown by defined the Fourier transform over the Schwartz space and then taking the norm closure.

I am wondering whether there is an explicit and computable example of a function $f \in L^2(\mathbb R) \setminus L^1(\mathbb R)$ whose Fourier transform can be computed explicitly. Ideally, the example should be suitable for an undergraduate class, i.e., as simple as possible.

Comment: Standard example: $\frac {\sin x }x$.

Comment: Can you give a reference where that example is fully worked out? It seems to depend on cancellation properties.

Comment: Compute the FT of the characteristic function of the interval $(-\frac  1{2\pi},\frac  1{2\pi})$.

Comment: I know. What is the best way of showing it is not absolutely integrable but has a well-defined Fourier transform?

Comment: @shuhalo Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the example $f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ as refernced in the comments.  Clearly, $f\in L^2$ since

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left|f(x)\right|^2\,dx&=\int_{|x|\le 1}\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right|^2\,dx+\int_{|x|\ge 1}\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right|^2\,dx\\\\
&\le \int_{-1}^1(1)^2\,dx+2\int_1^\infty \frac1{x^2}\,dx\\\\
&=4
\end{align}$$

Next, we show that $f\notin L^1$.  Proceeding, let $f^+$ and $f^-$ denote the positive and negative parts of $f$, respectively.  Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-(2N+2)\pi}^{(2N+2)\pi}\left|f(x)\right|\,dx&=2\int_{0}^{(2N+2)\pi} |f(x)|\,dx\\\\
&=2\int_{0}^{(2N+2)\pi} (f^+(x)-f^-(x))\\\\
&=2\sum_{n=0}^N \left(\int_{2n\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx\right)-2\sum_{n=0}^N \left(\int_{(2n+1)\pi}^{2(n+1)\pi}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx\right)\\\\
&\ge \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{4}{(2n+1)\pi}+\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{2}{n+1}\\\\
\end{align}$$

which clearly diverges as $N\to \infty$.

However, we have

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\{f\}(\xi)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}e^{-i2\pi \xi x}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{i(1-2\pi \xi) x}-e^{i(1+2\pi \xi) x}}{i2x}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin((1-2\pi \xi) x-\sin((1+2\pi \xi) x)}{2x}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\text{sgn}(1-2\pi \xi)-\text{sgn}(1+2\pi \xi)\right)
\end{align}$$

Comment: @shuhalo Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can